# Selenium: Trying to enter text in the active element without id but failing

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to enter text in the active element but failing.. 
Can anyone help? Code is as follows. element is commented on.
Using python and selenium and web driver.

using time to give breaks between code to wait for loading
keyboard shortcuts are used to enter the elements as names for gmail are not available.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

u = input("Enter username: ")

p = input("Enter password: ")

a = input("Enter email address(multiple separated by comma: ")

s = input("Enter subject: ")

t = input("Enter text: ")


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/identifier?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=AddSession')

userid = browser.find_element_by_name("identifier")
userid.send_keys(u)
userid.send_keys(u'\ue007')

time.sleep(2)

passw = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
passw.send_keys(p)
passw.send_keys(u'\ue007')

time.sleep(10)

browser.get('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=new')

time.sleep(5)

to = browser.find_element_by_name("to")
to.send_keys(a)
fr = browser.find_element_by_name("subjectbox")
fr.send_keys(s)
fr.send_keys(Keys.TAB)

x = browser.switch_to.active_element
time.sleep(1)
x.send_keys(t) #THIS IS NOT WORKING
```

Comment: print(x.get_attribute("outerHTML")) // This Line prints the Outer Html. Validate the outer html with your expected elements. If it is referring to some other element. You need to change the element identification strategy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `browser.switch_to.active_element` turns `x` into a `dict` whose 'value' key contains the Selenium web element you want to send keys to. I have no idea why that happens on Firefox, on Chrome your script works fine.

Anyway, use this to solve your problem:
`x['value'].send_keys(t)`

Comment: Oh.. Thank you. I shall try this out.